# Why is the module export variable empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraylist, rss

I'm new to nodejs.

Here is my .js file. I'm trying to expose audioData variable to other functions. audioData variable value is being empty outside the function. I see the value when I print inside the function. What could be wrong?

```
'use strict';
var asyncrequest = require('request');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parseString = xml2js.parseString;
var audioData = [];

asyncrequest("http://example.com/feed", function(error, responsemeta, body) {

    parseString(body, function(err, result){
            var stories = result['rss']['channel'][0]['item'];

            console.log("Total stories: " + stories.length);

            stories.forEach(function(entry) {
                var singleObj = {}
                singleObj['title'] = entry['title'][0];
                singleObj['value'] = entry['enclosure'][0].$.url;
                audioData.push(singleObj);
            });
    });
    console.dir(audioData);
});

module.exports = audioData;
console.log("Program ended");
```

Comment: You are performing an asynchronous request that modifies `audioData`. This request runs *after* the variable gets exported. Thus, an import using `require` will retrieve the empty array. It will stay empty until the request completes.

Comment: @heartyporridge IIRC `require()` is synchronous, so after the empty array is exported, it will stay that way even after the request is completed

Comment: @spicypumpkin Hm... but doesn't `require` return a reference? Correct me if I'm wrong, if it gets updated by the module it gets updated by whoever `require`s it.

Unless... each `require` generates a unique scope for the variable exported?

Comment: @heartyporridge Oh, you know what, I was wrong. It does return a reference. My bad haha

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to return a promise for the audioData, not the audioData itself! You can learn more about promises elsewhere. Happily there's a promisified version of request, request-promise, that you can use like so:

```
'use strict';

var rp = require('request-promise');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parseString = xml2js.parseString;
var audioData = [];

var promiseForAudioData = rp('http://example.com/feed')
  .then(body => {
    parseString(body, function(err, result){
      var stories = result['rss']['channel'][0]['item'];
      console.log("Total stories: " + stories.length);

      stories.forEach(function(entry) {
        var singleObj = {}
        singleObj['title'] = entry['title'][0];
        singleObj['value'] = entry['enclosure'][0].$.url;
        audioData.push(singleObj);
      });
    });

    return audioData;
  })
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));

module.exports = promiseForAudioData;
console.log("Program ended");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use promises, you can either export inside the callback or export the request method itself.

```
asyncrequest("http://example.com/feed", function(error, responsemeta, body) {

  parseString(body, function(err, result){

    var stories = result['rss']['channel'][0]['item'];    
    console.log("Total stories: " + stories.length);
    stories.forEach(function(entry) {
      var singleObj = {}
      singleObj['title'] = entry['title'][0]; 
      singleObj['value'] = entry['enclosure'][0].$.url; audioData.push(singleObj);
    });
    module.exports = audioData;

  }); 

});

// Or 
exports.get = function (callback) {
  return asyncrequest(/* ... */, callback);
}

// Other module
require("./module").get(function (audioData) {
  /* Do something */
})
```